# In manage users in Google Analytics, what does "none(user has permissions on a lower level) " mean?

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently going through our analytics account and removing old accounts. I have about 20 where the permissions says "**none(user has permissions on a lower level)** "

However when I try to find any other information on what "permissions on a lower level" actually means the help link does not explain anything and there is nothing to clarify what this permissions actually is.

I have looked through all the documentation and have not come across anything explains the "none"

Anyone have an idea on what this actually means, and if I can remove these accounts?

Edit 2: The users that have this have no permissions at Account, Property, or View Level

When I view them they have None next to each property, and then if I look at each Property at their view permissions they also have nothing for all of them.

Have added screenshot below.

[image: Google Analytics - User Permissions]

Edit 3: Turns out I wasn't looking carefully enough, I will add what helped me figure this out as it might beneficial to someone else.

If on a user you click '**View user's account details**'
[image]

This opens a tree structure to view the users permissions where you can see their access to every Property and View

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your analytics account Go to Admin.

Check "User Management" all the three columns i.e Account, Property and view.

Here there is an option to manage users where you can add users to an account, a property or a view.

There might be some users added by you, who have access only to a particular property or view, not to the account as a whole.

Remove the users from the Property/View Level.

Problem Solved!

I've attached a screenshot which might help.

[image: Screenshot of analytics admin page]

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are three 'layers': Account, Property, View.

So at Account level the lower levels are Property and View. And at Property level the lower level is View.

If you're in Property, and the interface says the user has permissions at a lower level, take a look at View.